# PHP notification functions incorrectly if over a certain number of users

Tags: php, android, api, push-notification

The following code works for 2 or 3 users as long as I limit my query to 3 people. When I try it for 2000 people it no longer sends a notification. I also receive  **success:0** in response.

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

            // Set POST variables

            $googleapikey="AIzaSyCeFfqiRt3xFzZH2XDwICJDZkasF7uWBJI";
            $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';



            $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids'  => $registatoin_ids,
                    'data'              =>  $message,
                    );


            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' . $googleapikey,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
            // Open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));




            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);

            $result1=json_decode($result);



    }
```

I'm also using the function above to call the function below to send my notifications. *My problem is*, It works when there are just 2 or 3 users, but when user's exceed 2000 it does not work as expected(sends notifications).

```
 $qry = mysql_query("SELECT deviceToken FROM app_devices");

            $devices = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
            {

                $devices[] =  $row['deviceToken'];

            }
             $gcm->send_notification($devices, $message);
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge we can at max send 1000 notifications from GCM at a time, so if u want to send more than that, divide the no of users into group of 1000 and send request in that manner.

For Eg:
If u want to send 2000 notifications then make 2 calls each having ids of 1000 users.

Comment: Yes create batch and send batch wise.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use `Firebase Cloud Messaging` because it is the evolution of `Google Cloud Messaging.`
Try to use this:

```
    $message = array ("message" => $bodyMail, "to" => $to, "From" => $from);
$id = array($to);
$message_status = sendPushNotification( $message, $id );

echo $message_status;

// Send push notification via Firebase Cloud Messaging


function sendPushNotification( $data, $ids )
{
    // Insert real FCM API key from the Google APIs Console

    $apiKey = "YourApiKey";
    // Set POST request body
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => $ids,
        'data'              => $data
    );

    // Set CURL request headers
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key =' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Initialize curl handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set URL to GCM push endpoint
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );

    // Set request method to POST
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    // Set custom request headers
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    // Get the response back as string instead of printing it
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    // Set JSON post data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    // Actually send the request
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    // Handle errors
    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
    {
        echo 'FCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    }

    // Close curl handle
    curl_close( $ch );

    // Debug GCM response
    return $result;
}
```